# Android emulator Java shell

Tags: java, android, shell, emulation

I'm working on a test generation tool and need to start the device to execute test cases. I have the following trial code

```
ProcessBuilder pb_d = new ProcessBuilder("emulator",  "-avd", "Nexus_5_API_19");
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting Device");
        Process process = pb_d.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        System.out.printf("Output of running \"emulator\",  \"-avd\", \"Nexus_5_API_19\"");

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "emulator": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I tried it with Runtime but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the full path of emulator or make sure system variable PATH already have config for emulator.exe

Comment: Just tried that. No luck :\ . The command runs fine with the terminal.

Comment: try this: `new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/C","start","emulator","-avd","Nexus_5_API_19");`

Comment: It is a mac but I tried `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal");
    p.waitFor();` and It opened the terminal but nothing after that :\ .

Comment: Never mind, I used the whole path to the emulator and it worked fine :). Thanks for the suggestions though. I already had the path in my environment variables but looks like I need to specify it explicitly. :D